# How can I send the first and second ascii characters as NULL character in a string and not as "" an empty string?

Tags: c, string, ascii

I am currently dealing with a problem that especially has something to do with the first and second ASCII characters, the NULL Character and SOH Character.
The goal of this code is to send some characters and save them in a Tag, which contains 32 Bits/4 Bytes Blocks where Data can be saved in.

I know that there are better ways to achieve this. My Code functions nearly properly except in one single case:

When the Character equals the first ASCII character NULL. Which means when I view the value of the character: c_Char="", when this get sent to the Tag, it doesnt count as an ascii character and gets skipped.

Which means when I check which Characters are sent, the Buffer does not return the character with the 0 decimal value since it was not saved and got skipped.

Is there any If-Condition that I can use to make my program count the NULL ascii character?
This is part of the main Code:

```
       // Splitting the 32 bits from B0 to 4 Bytes
        Daten_EEPROM_Byte_VERTEILER(B0); 
       // Converting The four 32 Bits/4 Bytes Variables into 4 different decimal numbers
        Data_Converting_binary_decimal(cFirst_Byte,&i_Char1);
        Data_Converting_binary_decimal(cSecond_Byte,&i_Char2);
        Data_Converting_binary_decimal(cThird_Byte,&i_Char3);
        Data_Converting_binary_decimal(cFourth_Byte,&i_Char4);
        //Converting the 4 decimal numbers into 4 ascii Chars.
        Fmt(c_Char1,"%c<%i", i_Char1);
        Fmt(c_Char2,"%c<%i",i_Char2);
        Fmt(c_Char3,"%c<%i",i_Char3);
        Fmt(c_Char4,"%c<%i",i_Char4);
        //Converting Ascii characters into hexadecimal numbers.
        DATEN_Umwandlungsfunktion_Char_hex      (c_Char1,  x_char1,  &iSeriennummer);
        DATEN_Umwandlungsfunktion_Char_hex      (c_Char2,  x_char2,  &iSeriennummer);
        DATEN_Umwandlungsfunktion_Char_hex      (c_Char3,  x_char3,  &iSeriennummer);
        DATEN_Umwandlungsfunktion_Char_hex      (c_Char4,  x_char4,  &iSeriennummer);   
        //Putting the 4 hex numbers into the  one variable:
        Fmt(x_Result_B0,"%s<%s%s%s%s",x_char1,x_char2,x_char3,x_char4);
        //Showing the 4 hex numbers in a panel:
        SetCtrlAttribute(sPanels.P_Hauptmenue, P_MAIN_WB0, ATTR_CTRL_VAL, x_Result_B0); 
        
        memset(x_char1,0,sizeof(x_char1));
        memset(x_char2,0,sizeof(x_char2));
        memset(x_char3,0,sizeof(x_char3));
        memset(x_char4,0,sizeof(x_char4));

        //Sending the 4 characters into a MSP430 Port to save them in a tag through an                  antenna
        Fmt(Result_Block0,"%s<%s%s%s%s",c_Char1,c_Char2,c_Char3,c_Char4);
        Fmt(cCommand,"%s<%s%s%s%s",WRITE_BLOCK,"0_",Result_Block0,ENDE);
        
        // Write and Read Data in and from Block 0 
        iResult = Befehl_Senden(cCommand,cAnswer);
        Fmt(cCommand,"%s<%s%s%s",READ_BLOCK,"0",ENDE);
        iResult = Befehl_Senden(cCommand,cAnswer);
        CopyBytes(cRead_Block_0,0,cAnswer,23,8);
        SetCtrlAttribute(sPanels.P_Hauptmenue, P_MAIN_BR0, ATTR_CTRL_VAL, cRead_Block_0);
```

These are the following functions that are used to convert the variables:

```
   char *decimal_to_binary(int n)
{  
 int c, d, t;
 char *p;

 t = 0;
 p = (char*)malloc(32+1);

 if (p == NULL)
   exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

 for (c = 31 ; c >= 0 ; c--)
 {
   d = n >> c;

   if (d & 1)
     *(p+t) = 1 + '0';
   else
     *(p+t) = 0 + '0';

   t++;
 }
 *(p+t) = '\0';

 return  p;
}  
void  Daten_HILFSFUNKTION_binary_decimal (char *cEingang, int *iAusgang)       
{
   int multiplier = 0;                 
   int i;                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   int sum = 0;
   int length;
   char cMonth[10] = {0};
   int iMonth;

   length =  StringLength (cEingang); 
   for (i=length-1; i>=0; i--)
   {
       CopyBytes (cMonth, 0, cEingang, i, 1);
       Fmt (&iMonth, "%x<%s", cMonth);
       sum = sum +(iMonth*pow(2, multiplier));
       multiplier = multiplier + 1;
   }   
   Fmt (iAusgang, "%i<%i", sum);
}

void Daten_EEPROM_Byte_VERTEILER(char *B)
{
           CopyBytes(cFirst_Byte, 0,B,0,8);
           CopyBytes(cSecond_Byte, 0,B,8,8);
           CopyBytes(cThird_Byte, 0,B,16,8);
           CopyBytes(cFourth_Byte, 0,B,24,8);
}
char  *Daten_EEPROM_HILFSFUNKTION(char *Char_in_Bits, char *c_8Bits)
{           
   int Decimal = 0;
   char c_Character[5] = {0};
   CopyString(Char_in_Bits, 0,c_8Bits,0,8);
   Daten_HILFSFUNKTION_binary_decimal (Char_in_Bits, &Decimal);
   int B_1_dec  = Decimal;
   Fmt(c_Character,"%c<%i",B_1_dec);

   memset(Char_in_Bits,0,sizeof(Char_in_Bits));
   return c_Character;
       
}
void    DATEN_alle_Char_uerbergabe_Funktion     (char *Byte_Block,char *c_Char1, char *c_Char2, char *c_Char3,char * c_Char4)
{
   DATEN_erster_Char_uebergabe_Funktion(Byte_Block, c_Char1);
   DATEN_zweiter_Char_uebergabe_Funktion(Byte_Block, c_Char2);
   DATEN_dritter_Char_uebergabe_Funktion(Byte_Block, c_Char3);
   DATEN_vierter_Char_uebergabe_Funktion(Byte_Block, c_Char4);
}

char  DATEN_erster_Char_uebergabe_Funktion  (char *Byte_Block,char *c_Char1)
{
           return* c_Char1 = *Daten_EEPROM_HILFSFUNKTION(Byte_Block,  cFirst_Byte);    

}
char  DATEN_zweiter_Char_uebergabe_Funktion(char *Byte_Block,char *c_Char2)
{
           return *c_Char2 = *Daten_EEPROM_HILFSFUNKTION(Byte_Block,  cSecond_Byte);   
}
char  DATEN_dritter_Char_uebergabe_Funktion(char *Byte_Block,char *c_Char3)
{

           return *c_Char3 = *Daten_EEPROM_HILFSFUNKTION(Byte_Block,  cThird_Byte);            
}


char  DATEN_vierter_Char_uebergabe_Funktion(char *Byte_Block,char *c_Char4)
{

           return *c_Char4 = *Daten_EEPROM_HILFSFUNKTION(Byte_Block,  cSecond_Byte);       
}
void char_Umwandeln (char *cEingang,char *cAusgang)
{
   int ilaenge;
   int idez_Wert;
   int iPos;
   char cZwischenspeicher [5] = {0};
   ilaenge = StringLength(cEingang);
   for (iPos = 0; iPos <=ilaenge - 1; iPos++)
   {
       idez_Wert = 0;
       //CopyBytes (cZwishcenspeicher, 0, cEingang, ilaenge-iPos,1);
       CopyBytes (cZwischenspeicher,0,cEingang,iPos,1);
       Scan (cZwischenspeicher,"%s>%i[r256]",&idez_Wert);
       if (idez_Wert == 0)
       {
           CopyBytes (cAusgang, 0,"00",0,2);
       }
       else if (idez_Wert <16)
       {
           Fmt(cAusgang,"%s<%s%s%i[r16]",cAusgang,"0",idez_Wert);
       }
       else 
       {
           Fmt(cAusgang,"%s<%s%i[r16]",cAusgang,idez_Wert);
       }
   }
   StringUpperCase(cAusgang);
}

void    DATEN_Umwandlungsfunktion_Char_hex      (char *Char, char *hex_Char, int *dec_Nummer) 
{
   
           char_Umwandeln (Char,hex_Char);
           Scan(&hex_Char,"%s>%x",&dec_Nummer);
}
```

If anyone has already had this problem and knows a solution for this issue, I would be so thankful. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: A `NULL` character indicates the end of a string, and thus cannot be part of its content.  But if you're working with just an array of characters, you don't have that restriction.

Comment: You are using a function named `StringLength`. But with code snippets and lots of helper functions, it isn't easy to know where the `NUL` is and how it is being processed.

Comment: @WeatherVaneThe StringLength Function is used for the strings that contain binary numbers. And the c_Char1 variable gets an empty string "" only because the i_Char was zero and I am not sure if there is a mistake in converting the variable from decimal to an ascii character.

Comment: @Ramles Why did you flag the comment? It's not rude - just true

Comment: @4386427 Sorry. I just saw that it was a quote. I was too fast.

Comment: Write code in English - never in your native language... unless it happens to be English

Comment: @4386427 Actually the functions are not that important to solve this problem. I just wanna know how can I let the Board that I have know that the char with the string value "" a NULL value and also needs to be taken into consideration.. This is my question :D

Comment: @4386427 I will! Thank you so much.

Comment: OT & BTW: Just love "Umwandlungsfunktion" ;-) Directly translated it would be amazing

Comment: *I have know that the char with the string value "" a NULL value*. You can't. By definition a NUL character terminates a string, but is not part of the data. You need arrays with a length argument.

Comment: @WeatherVane Perhaps add 1 when appropriate !?

Comment: @WeatherVane " By definition a NUL character terminates a string, but is not part of the data." --> The definition: "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null character." does not define which is part of data or not.  Agree a string does end with the first null character, yet the null character is part of the string.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Well the thing that is kind of confusing me is that NULL or the first ascii character is actually a character. But when I look how it is written in a code as a character, it is a "\0" which contains more than one character. So I do not know how to solve this problem or maybe adding an if condition in case the value of the variables equals the NULL or the first Ascii character...

Comment: @Ramles 1) Do not use a _stirng_ - a _string_ ends at the first _null chracteracter_.  Use an array of characters if data past the _null chracter_ is needed.  2) The term `NULL` is best as a _null pointer_, not a a _null chracter_.  Better to use _null character_ or perhaps `'\0'`.